# React native render component

Tags: react-native

I want to render a different thing for the logged in user. And what I want to show them is returned from a function. Maybe I'm doing everything wrong so I'd very appreciate your help.
This is the function the view is returned from:

```js
async function getchats()
{
  [...]

  var checked = 0
  var towrite = <CategoryCard
  titleText={chats.chatItems[checked].senderName}
  customDescriptionComponent={<Text fontSize={20}>{chats.chatItems[checked].message}</Text>}
  count={1}
  gradientColors={["#FAF9D1", "#EECA66", "#E8B730"]}
  onPress={() => console.log("Working")}
/>;
checked++
  while(checked != chats.chatItems.length)
  {
    towrite+=<CategoryCard
    titleText={chats.chatItems[checked].senderName}
    customDescriptionComponent={<Text fontSize={20}>{chats.chatItems[checked].message}</Text>}
    count={1}
    gradientColors={["#FAF9D1", "#EECA66", "#E8B730"]}
    onPress={() => console.log("Working")}
  />;
  checked++
  }
  return (
    <Root>
      {towrite}
    </Root>
  )
  
}
```

This is the render function:

```js
const YourApp = async () => {
  if(await AsyncStorage.getItem("token") != undefined)
  {
    var users = await getchats()
    return users
  }
    ...
  
}
```

I get this error:

```
Error: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {_U, _V, _W, _X}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.
```

I tried to create an array and push the CategoryCards in it, but I got the same error.

Comment: Maybe it's better you manipulate data like what exactly you want by looping and then save it to state and render it using `array.map`. That would be better i guess

Comment: Hi! It's working. Thank you

Comment: Glad to know @csanszan1